# avoid arrow crossing border of block TikZ in beamer

Tags: beamer, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, arrowwithtext

[image: Here is my situation]

I am writing a presentation in beamer but when adding the arrows to the "objective situation" and "Macro context" blocks they point inside the block , instead of pointing to the border. Can show me how to make the arrow point to the border?

Here is my MWE:

```
       \documentclass{beamer}
       \usetheme{Ilmenau}
       \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
       \usepackage{appendix}
       \usepackage[numberedbib]{apacite}
       \renewcommand\bibsection{\section[]{\refname}}
       \renewcommand\bibliographytypesize{\tiny}
       \usepackage{textpos}
       \usepackage{eurosym}
       \usepackage{tikz}
       \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
       \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

     \begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{}

    \tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=white, rectangle,  minimum height=3em, 
     minimum width=6em]
    \tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

    \begin{figure}[!h]
    \begin{center}

  \begin{tikzpicture} [auto,>=latex',every node/.append style= 
 {font=\footnotesize}]

  \node [block, name=input, node distance=1cm] (a2) {Subjective perception};
\node [block, above=of input, yshift=1cm ](a5) {Objective situation};
\node [block, below=of input, yshift=-1cm] (a1) {Macro context};
\node [block, right=of a2] (a3) {Fertility intentions};
\node [block, right=of a3] (a4) {Fertility realizations};

\draw [->] (a5) -- (input);
\draw [->] (a1) -- (input);
\draw [->] (a2) -- (a3);
\draw [->] (a3) -- (a4);

 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}
 \end{figure}
  \end{frame}


  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `\node [block, name=input, node distance=1cm] (a2) {Subjective perception};`, so you give the node a name twice, first `input` then `a2`. The `a2` name will overwrite `input`, so you get an error `no shape input is known`. Change `name=input` to `alias=input`, then you can refer to it by both names.

Comment: Great! I had not noticed this point. Thank you for your promt answer :)